# Activity counter in pure javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem with create activity script for 4 element on DOM. 
I can't use JQuery, must be write in pure JavaScript - it's practice for school... 
 1. The counter what i'am done work good but in next step i must divide html site for 4 part and any part must have his counter... so it's logical that i must use obiective javascript and there is problem...
 2. Any time when i try create 4 obiect the last, destroy another. 
 3. Generally does not work and I do not know why.

There is code:

```
<pre><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title>Example #6</title>
    <script>
      function T(div){
        var millis = 0;
        var sec = 0;
        var stopTime=0;
        var totalTime =0;
        var temp = 0;
        var startTime=0;
        var work = false;
          setStopTime = function(){
            stopTime = (new Date()).getTime() + 3000;
          }
          function setValue(value) {
            millis = Math.floor ( value % 1000 );
            value = Math.floor( value / 1000 );
            sec = Math.floor ( value % 60 );
            value = Math.floor( value / 60 );
            if( value < 10 ) { value="0" + value;
            if( sec < 10 ) { sec = "0" + sec; }
            else if( millis < 100 ) { millis = "00" + millis; }
            }
          document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = value + ":" + sec +"." + millis;
          }
          go2 = function() {
            if ( work == true ) return;
            work = true;
            document.getElementById(div).style.backgroundColor="red";
            var currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
            startTime = currentTime;
            var counter = setInterval(function() {
          if(currentTime >= stopTime){
          document.getElementById(div).style.backgroundColor="";
          clearInterval(counter);
          totalTime+= stopTime - startTime;
          work = false;
          setValue(totalTime);
          return;
          }
          temp = currentTime - startTime;
          setValue(temp+totalTime);
          currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
          }, 1);
        }
     addEventListener("mousemove",  function() {setStopTime();go2();});
     addEventListener("keydown",  function() {setStopTime();go2();});
    }


    var obj1 = new T('obj1');
    var obj2 = new T('obj2');
    var obj3 = new T('obj3');
    var obj4 = new T('obj4');



  </script>
    </head>
  <body>

      <div id="obj1"><p>counter1</p></div>
      <div id="obj2"><p>counter2</p></div>
      <div id="obj3"><p>counter3</p></div>
      <div id="obj4"><p>counter4</p></div>

  </body>
</html></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

`go2` and `setStopTime` must be local.

```
var setStopTime = function(){...
var go2 = function() {
```